# Selenium firefox webdriver unknown error using GeckoDriver and Python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, webdriver, geckodriver

I've created many test cases using:

- Firefox v55
- Python 2.7.3
- GeckoDriver v0.19.0

This scenario is beeing used by around 50 test cases

```
try:
    caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
    caps["wires"] = True
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps)
    driver.maximize_window()

    self.log("Selenium driver created for %s" % browser)
    return self.STATUS.PASS, driver

except Exception, e:
    self.log("Error when creating selenium driver")
    self.log(traceback.format_exc())
    return self.STATUS.FAIL
```

This code simple creates a Firefox web driver, and it is working fine in all the test cases but 1, in one in particular when I execute it in a daily execution i got the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\QA Tools\selenium\CreateSeleniumDriver.py", line 26, in run

driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps)

File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.5.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
keep_alive=True)

File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.5.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 140, in __init__
self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)

File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.5.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 229, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)

File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.5.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 295, in execute
response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)

File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.5.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 464, in execute
return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)

File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.5.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 538, in _request
body = data.decode('utf-8').replace('\x00', '').strip()

File "c:\python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'utf_8_decode'

Selenium driver created for Firefox
Error when creating selenium driver
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\QA Tools\selenium\CreateSeleniumDriver.py", line 63, in run
return self.STATUS.PASS, driver

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'driver' referenced before assignment
```

So, this is breaking a part of selenium web driver, but i have no idea why!

- I've tried everything to make it work
- This works in all other scenarios I'm using it
- This only happens on Firefox
- This works if it is executed manualy, but not working when executed on a daily execution with all others test cases (any related to this kind of execution was checked and not problem found)

Any ideas what could be going on wrong?

Comment: I think the issue might have something to do with the try/except if an exception is raised before the driver assignment and handled by the except. Would you add that code to your example?

Comment: Added detailed code with try/except

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you're running into this bug filed on the official Python bug tracker: https://bugs.python.org/issue14847

The comments there suggest that the issue might be related to one of two things:

1. Installing packages with `distribute`, due to a bug known to exist at least in `distribute 0.6.26`. If your "daily execution" relies on installing with this bugged version of `distribute`, that may explain your issue. Do you know if you do this? And can you update the version of `distribute` used in your environment, or perhaps use virtual environments to avoid it?
2. Some other way of manipulating `sys.modules` such that `codecs` is not found and gives `None` instead. Does your code do anything like this in some kind of fancy test setup?

Judging by the trace, you've modified your code for brevity, but in a way that might not completely capture the original logic. The `UnboundLocalError` suggests that your assignment of `driver` was skipped, and you didn't return right away:

```
try:
    caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
    caps["wires"] = True
    # This line raises an AttributeError deep inside a standard python lib:
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps)
    driver.maximize_window()

    self.log("Selenium driver created for %s" % browser)

except Exception, e:
    # The driver variable was never actually created or assigned due to the
    # AttributeError above.
    self.log("Error when creating selenium driver")
    self.log(traceback.format_exc())

# Some omitted code...

# The driver variable does not exist past the try if the exception happened
# before assignment to driver. So this raises the UnboundLocalError:
return self.STATUS.PASS, driver
```

You can fix `UnboundLocalError` pretty easily by doing the return inside the except, or pre-assigning `driver` to `None` or something, but that won't fix the underlying issue creating the driver. That sounds like an issue with your execution environment. Maybe something in your run infrastructure is doing something fancy (what are you using as your test runner?) or perhaps there's something corrupt in the Python environment of your daily execution runner. Depending on what the issue is, you might be able to solve the problem by defining a specific `virtualenv` for all test execution, so you can be sure it runs the same manually as it does in the automatic daily execution.

Comment: 1. This daily execution uses easy_install to install dependencies modules, I've made the best search I can (cause its a huge framework) but found nothing related to distribute, so I'm guessing no, I dont use any version of distribute.-

2. Not at all, there is not any fancy setup like that.-

Do you imagine any workaround to this issue? I mean, my problem is that selenium web driver is failing, i should not edit any code in there to bypass this error. I'm really stuck.-

Thank you so much for your help and time. I will look deeper in that python error u gave me.-

Comment: @ArgiesDario Would you please update your question to include the daily kickoff logic? It might also help if you can describe any other differences between the daily kickoff and the manual execution (like, is the python version the same, is it on the same OS, etc.). This fundamentally doesn't look like a Selenium Webdriver issue because the original exception is about how the "codecs" module (a default Python package!) is broken/missing. I might have some suggestions about how to change the daily kickoff, if you can modify that.